# Does the minionpro package has problems with spacing in math mode (like mathspec)?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, mathspec

I recently started using the open type `Minion Pro` font with `mathspec` in `XeLaTeX`. But I noticed a major drawback: `mathspec` has problems with character spacing in math mode because `Minion Pro` is not a true math font. My question is, does the `minionpro` package for `LaTeX` deal with this problem in anyway? or should I just continue using `mathspec` and try to adjust the character spacing manually?

This probably warrants its own post, but is using the `MnSymbol` package benefit when using `mathspec`? So far my formulas containing Greek letters are displaying correctly without loading `Mnsymbol`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! Have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: BTW, there is an OpenType [Minion Math](http://www.typoma.com/en/fonts.html) font that can be used with `unicode-math` package.

Comment: @KhaledHosny, thanks for the suggestion, but those fonts seem to be very expensive. Nothing an student can afford...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is accepted, but I'm going to answer my own question in case someone finds this page.
It appears that `minionpro` (and `myriadpro`) DOES deal with math specific kerning and spacing.

I used the [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) scripts to convert the MinionPro opentype font included in Adobe CS to the Type1 format and install the 'minionpro' package (the script deals with everything). Then I invoked it using `\usepackage[textlf,mathlf,minionint]{MinionPro}` (no need to load MnSymbol as it is loaded automatically). The results are beautiful:
[image]

Compare this to the output produced by the `mathspec` package and `xetex` (even with mathspec option `\setminwhitespace[1000]` to manually increase the spacing):[image]
Notice how the spacing, particularly between the 'f' and the '(' and between the 'e' and 'j' is not correct. Also, the `\varepsilon` command seems to print the symbol using Computer Modern. To be fair, `mathspec` does provide a way to manually adjust the spacing on a character by character basis, but it was well worth the trouble to install 'minionpro' the old-fashioned way and let it take care of the kerning. As a plus, I can now use the `microtype` package to its full capacity.